# Why would a user's changes be overwritten without mention of a conflict?

Tags: git

I am working on a two person team. I made some changes to a file called PostSet. I pushed those changes. My partner had also made changes to the same file, and even to the same query. He ran

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

in order to put his changes on top of mine and keep the working history clean, as we always do. Normally we get conflicts if we edit the same line.

He was notified of a whole bunch of conflicts relating to some image files (a completely different issue). Just to explain everything, he fixed that problem by using

```
git rm -r path/to/image/dir
```

and then

```
git add -A
```

to add all of those changes to the index. After using

```
git rebase --continue
```

there were no more conflicts. We immediately noticed, however, that the relevant query was now using MY changes, not his. In fact, the entire file PostSet was on an old version after the rebase.

Shouldn't there have been some sort of conflict warning about the PostSet file? Is there something we did wrong with the rebase?

In short, we can't confidently continue development until we know changes will stop being overridden, so we're fairly frustrated.

Thanks a lot,

Paragon

Edit: We replicated our steps exactly and got the same result.

Edit: Given that nobody seems to have any clue, I will likely be reporting this as a bug in git. I'll leave it up for a while longer on the off chance that someone has a wild suggestion.

Comment: Nowhere in your description says that your partner changes were commited before the rebase. Is that the case?

Comment: git wouldn't allow a pull without all existing changes being committed. He committed his changes, then rebased, and his changes were already run-over before he could push back to the github repo.

Comment: 1. Seems like a bug that uncommited changes block the rm command and merge conflicts don't

2. I tried the same steps and rm gave a warning about the conflicting file needing a merge

3. Also, I ended without the conflicting file. Is there some option missing in the rm command?

Comment: What do you mean by "I ended without the conflicting file."? Also, what files were you trying to rm? I'd be fairly surprised if using `git rm` on unrelated files affects a conflicted file.

Comment: Can you use "git log" after the rebase to find the commit that should have had this change, and use "git show <commit-id>" to look at it?

Comment: Hm.  Are you _sure_ the commit your partner made, pre pull/rebase, is on his local branch after completing the rebase?  I can only think that it's being dropped or altered somewhere along the way.

Comment: @RsrchBoy Unfortunately my memory is failing me on this. I did check a number of diffs between commits, and I have some memory of seeing it there, but I'm just not sure enough. Our 'solution' was for him to reset to an earlier commit and have *him* push first, followed by me rebasing instead. This worked just fine, and we had to move on. Given that the history was changed in our repository, I am unable to go back and replicate the issue. (Sorry, ComputerDruid, but I can no longer perform the relevant "git log").

Answer (score 1):

I did the same steps using git version 1.7.3.1.
After the step:

```
git rm -r path/to/image/dir
```

The file PostSet is still in conflict mode, you can verify by requesting that status (here is my output):

```
$ git status -s
UU PostSet
D  images/test.jpg
```

Now you still need to solve the conflict in PostSet. 
If you skip that and execute instead

```
git add -A
```

you get the following case where git considers it as a solved conflict while you haven't actually done that:

```
$ git status -s
M  PostSet
D  images/test.jpg
```

So better to solve the conflict first and use afterwards `git add -A`

Or I might be missing some information here?